# Uniformization for possibly singular analytic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Is there a classification of the simply-connected one-dimensional complex analytic spaces?

Comment: In case of one dimensional are there precise description of the singularities? e.g. are they all cusp/nodal?

Comment: I don't know. (In the algebraic case I think there's no good description.)